# Declaring dynamic Multi-Dimensional pointer

Tags: c, pointers

Is it possible to declare a N-Dimension pointer during runtime? like, if [N = 2, **p], [N = 3, ***p], [N = 4, ****p] , and so on. If so, how ?

Comment: You can declare a pointer, a pointer to that pointer, and again another pointer to that one, …, no problem.

Comment: Please tag which language this is for? Thanks.

Comment: No, this is not possible. The types of all expressions must be known at compile-time in C, except for the actual length of an array dimension.

Comment: Also note: *Becoming a 3-Star Programmer* is not a necessarily compliment in C.

Comment: Do you need an N-dimensional pointer (then not cleanly) or N-dimensional array (then yes, just compute the offset into memory and use a simple pointer)?

Comment: A pointer is a scaler. And it's not an array. None of your approaches is even close to a multidimensional array.

Answer (score 2):

Possibly, it's not what you want, but you can define general **void *** pointer and then cast them depending on the **N**.

Ugly example:

```
void *genericPtr;
if (1 == N) {
    int *ptr = (int *)genericPtr;
    // your code here
} else if (2 == N) {
    int **ptr = (int **)genericPtr;
    // your code here
}
```

Comment: Presuming that `genericPtr` actually points to valid memory containing data for that type. Above, you have simply shown a cast of an uninitialized pointer. I assume this was just an example of how a void pointer could be used.

Comment: Yeah, just a demonstration.

Comment: This is an awful approach. Do you hate your compiler that much completely bypassing type checking? Its extremely error-prone. Additionally an `int **` cannot represent a 2D array.

Comment: First, I wrote that it's UGLY example. Second, int ** can represent array of pointers to arrays which is kind of 2D array. Third, the question was is it possible or not, without any 2D arrays.